# Can OS X dump cores in the working directory instead of /cores?

Tags: macos, kernel

I don't know when it started, but at some point, OS X started dumping cores into a special folder (`/cores`). This is a pain since they get jumbled together and it's hard to keep track of which core files goes with which execution. Is there an environment variable or special flag I can set to have cores dumped into the working directory (as with other operating systems) instead?

Comment: You can stop the cores in several ways: - delete the /cores directory
- set `ulimit -c 0` or limit core file size to some value that's small enough that you don't mind small dumps

Comment: I'm actually not that concerned about stopping the dumps. That's relatively straightforward and easy information to find. The real question I was targeting here was the location change. I did find the answer, but it's longer than a mobile post. I'll put it up soon.

Comment: I thought OSX always dumped to /cores so I assumed you had none previously.  We can host the "how to stop them entirely" answer on a different question.

Comment: This changed at some point. Either Lion or Mountain Lion I think, I don't remember. Previously, it behaved like every other OS and dumped them in the current working directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally figured this out. It turns out that this is a kernel parameter controlled by `sysctl`. You can set this on a per shell basis to dump in the current working directory with:

```
sysctl -w kern.corefile=core.%P
```

Since I never wanted my core dumps to end up in `/cores`, but always in the current directory, I added this `plist` to `/Library/LaunchDaemons/`:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>sysctl</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/sbin/sysctl</string>
        <string>-w</string>
        <string>kern.corefile=core.%P</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**UPDATE:**

Since I wrote this, it looks like the `sysctl` command changed. I've updated the examples above, but if you were previously using `kern.core_pattern`, that doesn't work anymore.